# delay modules preload after first app rendering

Tags: angular

I'm currently working on a single page app.
in the main page several card are displayed.
These cards may be enabled or disabled.
If disabled, only the title of the card is displayed.
If enabled, the title plus the content (which is lazy loaded) of the card is displayed
By default all cards are displyed and disabled.
According to user's dossier, some cards may be active when loading the page.

Currently, I didn't set any preloadingStrategy, thus, when loading the page, only the content of active card are loaded.

I have tried to set preloadingStrategy to preloadAllModules, it works fine, but it slow down the app start up. Actually, the content of active cards appear slower as all modules are loaded at the same time.

=> What I want is :
1. load the app
2. load the content of all active cards
3. preload all other modules that are not shown at startup

=> Some kind of delaying the preload after first rendering

=> Do you think that its possible ?

Thanks in advance for your feedback

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe it's possible, you have to make a custom preload strategy:

You can update your root router configuration like this:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CustomPreload implements PreloadingStrategy {
  preload(route: Route, load: () => Observable<any>): Observable<any> {
    // you implement this function somewhere, somehow
    if (isActiveCardRoute(route)) {
      // this will make it load immediately
      return load();
    } else {
      /* 
       * this will load the remaining modules after 5 seconds. You can possibly make a more
       * 'complex' logic to have it load sequentially or in bigger intervals to make sure
       * the app doesn't lag when loading
      */
      return timer(5000).pipe(
        switchMap(() => load())
      )
    }
  }
}
```

If somehow you need to find out before this, if a card is active or not by loading the api/logging in. You need to add this logic to the `APP_INITIALIZER`, or I guess you can add it to the `CustomPreload` as well, by injecting the appropriate services.

This `CustomPreload`, you can add to your `RouterConfig`:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes, {
  preloadingStrategy: CustomPreload
});
```

Comment: Nice answer - deserves more upvotes - I used this answer in combination with https://angular.io/guide/router#custom-preloading-strategy - largely relying on the Angular example but lifting your timing code - given my app is BIG no timing causes problems on initial page load - In the Angular example they use ... data: { preload: true } ... that is, they use route data to determine whether the route is preloaded - I changed this route data from a boolean to an integer and this integer controls the timing of the preload - if no integer is provided then the route aint preloaded

Comment: I have notice that `preload` methos is launched only for non active modules. Solution seems to work without `isActiveCardRoute` logic, hmmm...

Comment: @WalterLuszczyk that is true, but I believe this question was for lazy loaded modules inside other lazy loaded modules. So if you `/foo/bar` and `/foo/pub` as paths, where the path `/foo`, `/foo/bar` and `/foo/pub` are lazy loaded modules. It should also preload `/foo/pub` when you first navigate to `/foo/bar`. Do I make sense? :)

Answer (score 1):

I've created a short video explanation of how to create a Custom Preloading Strategy - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tDQc3CCvKfc
where it's shown how to create a delay and make preloading optional

and here is the code - https://github.com/stevermeister/AngularPro-Screencast/tree/master/code/Season4-Router-Features/preloading